# SQL Update most recent in table instead of most recent on selected record

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, max

I need to update members records that haven't attended in the past 14 days. 
There are two tables: Members and Attendance. I need to update the member record with the most recent "Last_Attend_Date" if the Attend_Freq is less than 5 over the last 14 days.

```
 Members table:
 ID     Attend_Freq     Last_Attend_Date
123        4              2012-7-5  -- This is the result of the query, the most 
                                       recent date in the table instead of the 
                                       most recent for the member

 Attendance
 ID     Member_ID       Last_Attend_Date
 987      123               2012-6-5
 888      123               2012-6-4
 567      123               2012-6-3
 456      234               2012-6-30
1909      292               2012-7-5
```

This is the query but its giving me the most recent Last_Attend_Date in the Attendance table instead of the most recent from the member that I need to update.

```
 UPDATE M
 SET Last_Attend_Date = 
 (SELECT Max(Last_Attend_Date) FROM Attendance A 
 JOIN Members M ON A.Member_ID = M.ID 
 WHERE A.Member_ID =M.id )
 FROM Members M
 JOIN Attendance A on A.Member_ID = M.id
 WHERE Attend_Freq <'5' and Last_Attend_Date <getdate()-14 and A.Member_ID = M.ID
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you're not correlating your subquery with your outer query. It helps to use different aliases for all tables involved, and the join to `Members` inside the subquery seems unnecessary:

```
create table Members (ID int not null,Attend_Freq int not null,Last_Attend_Date datetime not null)
insert into Members (ID,Attend_Freq,Last_Attend_Date) values
(123,4,'19000101')

create table Attendance (ID int not null,Member_ID int not null,Last_Attend_Date datetime not null)
insert into Attendance (ID,Member_ID,Last_Attend_Date) values
(987,123,'20120605'),
(888,123,'20120604'),
(567,123,'20120603'),
(456,234,'20120630'),
(1909,292,'20120705')

update M
set
    Last_Attend_Date =
        (select MAX(Last_Attend_Date)
            from Attendance A2
        where A2.Member_ID = M.ID) --M is a reference to the outer table here
from
    Members M
        inner join
    Attendance A
        on
            M.ID = A.Member_ID
where
    m.Attend_Freq < 5 and
    A.Last_Attend_Date < DATEADD(day,-14,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)

select * from Members
```

Result:

```
ID          Attend_Freq Last_Attend_Date
----------- ----------- ----------------
123         4           2012-06-05
```

Comment: Thank you. This works perfectly and I learned something along the way. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Using the [`ROW_NUMBER()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) function, you can rank all attendance records per member, starting from the latest, then, for every member, get the latest (i.e. top-ranked) record if it is for the day two weeks ago. Using the results (e.g. with the help of a join), you can now update the `Members` table, additionally checking if `Attend_Freq < 5`:

```
WITH AttendanceRanked AS (
  /* rank the rows per attendance date (in descending order) */
  SELECT
    *,
    rnk = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Member_ID
                                 ORDER BY Last_Attend_Date DESC)
  FROM Attendance
),
LastAttendance AS (
  /* get the latest attendance records per member */
  SELECT *
  FROM AttendanceRanked
  WHERE rnk = 1
    AND Last_Attend_Date <= DATEADD(DAY, -14, GETDATE())
)
/* join the latest attendance records with Members and
   update those members that match the additional condition */
UPDATE m
SET Last_Attend_Date = a.Last_Attend_Date
FROM Members m
  INNER JOIN LastAttendance a ON m.Member_ID = a.Member_ID
WHERE m.Attend_Freq < 5
;
```